# [Android]react-native-share: How to share an image to whatsapp on specific mobile number

Tags: android, react-native

I want to share selected `image` from my `app` to only selected `number` on `whatsapp`. Currently [react-native-share](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share) let me to select the `recepient's number` from`whatsapp`, but I want it to be directly shared to `specific number` I specified.

I tried using `whatsappNumber`:`9199999999`, but it doesn't worked.

```
const shareOptions = {
          title: 'Share via whatsapp',
          message: 'some message',
          url: "data:image/png;base64,"+base64,
          social: Share.Social.WHATSAPP,
          whatsAppNumber: "9199999999"
      };
 Share.shareSingle(shareOptions);
```

I'm not getting the exact intention of `whatsappNumber`. I'm trying to send the `message` directly to `9199999999`, but it's letting me to select the contact in `whatsapp`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. You can only open up a menu where you can select a contact and share it that way.

[See this link from the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/share)

Comment: I'm using react-native-share, not the Share class by react-native.